# Is there a numpy style was to multiply two arrays elementwise?

Tags: python, numpy

Here is an example of a code that performs elementwise multiplication for two 1D arrays of different size and returns a new, desired 2D array:

```
a = np.array([1, 2, 3, 4])
b = np.array([1, 10, 100])

np.array(list(map(lambda a_i: a_i * b, a)))

>>> array([[  1,  10, 100],
          [  2,  20, 200],
          [  3,  30, 300],
          [  4,  40, 400]])
```

However, I am curious, is there a native numpy feature for that?

Comment: I think numpy.outer will help. See https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.outer.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two options:

```
import numpy as np

a = np.array([1, 2, 3, 4])
b = np.array([1, 10, 100])

c = a[:, None] * b
print(c)

d = np.outer(a, b)
print(d)
```

Results:

```
[[  1  10 100]
 [  2  20 200]
 [  3  30 300]
 [  4  40 400]]
[[  1  10 100]
 [  2  20 200]
 [  3  30 300]
 [  4  40 400]]
```